# SQL Full Outer Join - Eliminate replicated column data

Tags: sql, join, outer-join

I wonder if anyone can help modify my SQL query that i created to query data based on a select parameter of date to date. The problem im facing is that im getting repeated contract numbers being displayed in the result set due to multiple results in the fitting table of the same contract number. Would it be possible to just filter the results down to just one contact number?

Here is my query:

```
select co.contractdate condate, ff.date_ fitdate, co.contractno conno, cu.surname Surname 
from contract co 
  full outer join co_fitt ff on co.contractno = ff.contractno 
  full outer join customer cu on co.custref = cu.custref 
WHERE co.contractdate between '01/jan/2016' and '31/jan/2016' 
order by co.contractno
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT co.contractdate condate,
       ff.date_        fitdate,
       co.contractno   conno,
       cu.surname      Surname
FROM   contract co
       FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT contractno
                        FROM   co_fitt) ff
                    ON co.contractno = ff.contractno
                       AND co.contractdate BETWEEN '01/jan/2016' AND '31/jan/2016'
       FULL OUTER JOIN customer cu
                    ON co.custref = cu.custref
ORDER  BY co.contractno
```

Instead of

```
co.contractno as conno
```

using

```
COALESCE(co.contractno,ff.contractno) as conno
```

will make more sense

Also move the `contractdate` filter to `ON` condition else `FULL OUTER JOIN` will be implicitly converted to `INNER JOIN`. Not matched records from `contract` table will have `NULL` values in `contractdate` column which will get filtered when you filter the `contractdate` in `Where` clause